# Cron job to execute every second wednesday every month is running on friday

Tags: cron

I have scheduled a cronjob in ubi-minimal os docker container in eks to run at: "30 12 8-14 * 2/3".
This is supposed to run every second wednesday of every moth but it got trigger today as well i.e. on 06/02/2023.

I am not getting what is going wrong, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The cron expression you have provided is not correct for running a job every second Wednesday of every month. The expression you have provided will run the job "at 12:30 PM, between day 8 and 14 of the month, every 3 days of the week, Tuesday through Saturday" ([Source](https://crontab.cronhub.io/))

You can use some special characters like "?" and "#" in order to create the desired expression.

The correct expression is

> 30 12 0 ? * 3#2 *

[More about special characters in CRON expressions.](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/symantec-security-software/endpoint-security-and-management/cloud-workload-protection-for-storage/1-0/Scan_Configuration_7/about-special-characters-in-cron-expressions-v123769576-d4995e65374.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its failing to parse '#' in the cron.

Comment: Try this instead:

30 12 * * 3 [ "$(date '+\%a')" = "Wed" ] && [ "$(date '+\%d')" -ge 8 ] && [ "$(date '+\%d')" -le 14 ] && your-command.

Replace your-command with the actual command you want to run.